# Writing temp file in tomcat 7.0 fails

Tags: java, tomcat7

I try to write a temporary file from a tomcat 7.0 application. It fails:

Servlet code snippet:

```
  File formFile = File.createTempFile("document", ".pdf");
```

Exception

```
  java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1879)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1923)
    at goGet(ServletTest.java:20)}
```

I guess catalina.policy is in the way.
How can I enable temp files for Web Applications?

Comment: You should **never** create files in your Tomcat folder installation nor in some path of your web application folder. You should have a dedicated folder to storage this files, and a *temp* folder where you will storage the temporary files.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use the JDK method for creating temp files?

Comment: I never said you to not use the JDK to create temp files. I said that you must not create them nor in your tomcat folder installation nor in your web application deployment folder (nor in any subfolder of it). Create a folder somewhere in your disk outside these folders, give the user enough permissions to create new files, and then create your new files there.

Comment: I found the problem myself: temp directory was missing in tomcat

Comment: @user2088476 can you add your answer as an official Answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem myself: temp directory was missing in tomcat.

Answer (score 5):

Tomcat was missing a temp directory.

Above issue got fixed on tomcat by creating a temp directory in tomcat base directory(cataline_home directory).

Comment: starting from what version?